# How subsets are defined in Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider four dimensional Lie algebra with non-zero commutations:

$[e_{2},e_{3}]=e_{1}, [e_{2}, e_{4}]=e_{2}, [e_{3}, e_{4}]=-e_{3}$

having sub-algebras $S_{1}=\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}, S_{2}=\{e_{1}+e_{2}\}, S_{3}=\{e_{1}+e_{4}, e_{3}\}, S_{4}=\{e_{3}\}$.

In terminology of sub-sets as defined in general set theory, how $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are comparable ?

Is $S_{4}$ is sub-set of $S_{3}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that subsets are not enough here, since we are dealing with vector spaces. So we need *subspaces*. A Lie subalgebra is a linear subspace which is closed under the Lie bracket. In your example, $S_1=span(e_1,e_2)$ is an abelian subalgebra of dimension $2$.

Comment: When one says, algebra L is contained in algebra G, does that mean L is subspace of S ?

Comment: You mean, does that mean that $L$ is a subspace of $G$ ? Yes, it does.